# What are the file name limitations in an FTP path?

Tags: ftp, files, name

What characters are allowed and what is the maximum length of a filename in an FTP path?

And can the rules be different between the various FTP servers?

Any other limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP protocol specification does not impose any rules on a file path.

All it says ([RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959), section 2.2) is:

> Pathname is defined to be the character string which must be
> input to a file system by a user in order to identify a file.
> Pathname normally contains device and/or directory names, and
> file name specification.  FTP does not yet specify a standard
> pathname convention.  **Each user must follow the file naming
> conventions of the file systems involved in the transfer.**

The original specification allowed 7-bit characters only, but this restriction was dropped in later [RFC 2640](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2640) ([section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2640#section-3)), which requires UTF-8 encoding.

So any character or length rules are system- and/or implementation-specific.